# no appropriate script or program found: fmtutil

Tags: pdftex, fmtutil

I am interested in the w32tex distribution. I downloaded from here:

https://ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/win32/w32tex/TLW64

then run this command:

```
pdflatex a.tex
```

Result:

```
runscript.tlu:858: no appropriate script or program found: fmtutil
```

This doesnt make sense as `fmtutil.exe` is right there in the `bin\win64`
folder. Calling it directly gives the same result:

```
> fmtutil.exe
runscript.tlu:858: no appropriate script or program found: fmtutil
```

As a workaround, I tried this instead:

http://ctan.ijs.si/mirror/w32tex/current/web2c-w32.tar.xz

and it works fine:

```
> fmtutil.exe
Commands:
--all                     recreate all format, base, mem files
--missing                 create all missing format, base, mem files
```

Comment: Important!!!
`https://ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/win32/w32tex/TLW64`
is not a part of `W32TeX`. Sorry for the name of the
parent directory. The directory contains 64bit binaries
for `TeX Live`.  One should install `TeX Live 2020` before
obtaining `tl-win64.zip`.
Please read `00README.TLW64` carefully.

Comment: 64bit binaries for `W32TeX` are
in `.../w32tex/win64`.
Many binaries for `W32TeX` and for `TeX Live for Windows` are the same.
However, directory structure and configurations are different.

Comment: @AkiraKakuto please see this issue as well  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/539208